# Filesystem-backed data structure?

Tags: c#, .net, file

Imagine a data structure like so:

```c#
public class Cat
{
    public string Name;
    public string FavoriteFood;
    public List<Memory> Memories;
}

public class Memory
{
    public string Name;
    public DateTime Date;
    public List<string> Thoughts;
}
```

Sometimes, `Cat`s will have many `Memories`, each with many thoughts. This can take an extraordinary amount of space, so keeping it in memory might not be the best idea. **What's the best way to back this data with files and folders?**

This would be nice not only for memory efficiency but also rather convenient for human usability if someone wanted to take a look at the data. An ideal filesystem might look like this.

```
\---Cats
    +---Charles
    |   |   cat.json
    |   |
    |   \---Memories
    |       |   eating_food.json
    |       |   sleeping.json
    |       |   biting_some_dude.json
    |
    \---Brumpbo
        |   cat.json
        |
        \---Memories
            |   sleeping.json
            |   sleeping_again.json
```

`cat.json` files might look something like this:

```json
{
    "name": "Charles",
    "favorite_food": "pant",
    "memories": [
        "eating_food",
        "sleeping",
        "biting_some_dude"
    ]
}
```

Memory files might look something like this (note that `thoughts` could be extremely long):

```json
{
    "name": "eating_food",
    "date": "2009-01-20T12:00:00.000Z",
    "thoughts": [
        "God, I love pant.",
        "This is some great pant.",
        // ...
        "I am never going to eat ever again.",
        "This was a mistake."
    ]
}
```

---

My first attempt at implementing this was to use `IDisposable` for serialization.

```c#
public class Cat : IDisposable
{
    public string Name;
    public string FavoriteFood;
    public List<string> Memories;

    // Load a cat if it already exists, or create a new one.
    public Cat(string name)
    {
        if (Storage.DirectoryExists(name))
        {
            var info = Storage.ReadFile<CatInfo>($"{name}/cat.json");
            this.Name = info.Name;
            this.FavoriteFood = info.FavoriteFood;
            this.Memories = info.Memories;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Memories = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public Memory GetMemory(string name)
    {
        if (this.Memories.Contains(name))
        {
            return new Memory(this, name);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Serialize and store the cat.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var info = new CatInfo
        {
            Name = this.Name,
            FavoriteFood = this.FavoriteFood,
            Memories = this.Memories
        };
        Storage.WriteFile("${this.Name}/cat.json", info);
    }
}

public Memory : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Cat cat;

    public string Name;
    public DateTime Date;
    public List<string> Thoughts;

    public Memory(Cat cat, string name)
    {
        if (Storage.FileExists($"{cat.Name}/Memories/{name}.json"))
        {
            var info = Storage.ReadFile<MemoryInfo>($"{cat.Name}/Memories/{name}.json");
            this.Name = info.Name;
            this.Date = info.Date;
            this.Thoughts = info.Thoughts;
        }
        else
        {
            this.Thoughts = new List<string>();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        var info = new MemoryInfo
        {
            Name = this.Name,
            Date = this.Date,
            Thoughts = this.Thoughts
        };
        Storage.WriteFile($"{this.cat.Name}/Memories/{this.Name}.json", info);
    }
}
```

Terrible as this may be, it works quite well until one issue comes up: thread safety. Imagine this: Charles the `Cat` discovers he likes to eat "bread" more than he likes to eat "pant." Now this necessitates two changes; one to the `Cat.FavoriteFood` field, and an addition to `Cat.Memories`. However, these two changes are likely handled by two separate processes in the application. This could result in a loss of data.

```
Thread 1: Charles is loaded to update FavoriteFood.
Thread 2: Charles is loaded to update Memories.
Thread 1: Charles's FavoriteFood is updated to "bread."
Thread 2: Charles's Memories is updated to include "eating_bread."
Thread 1: Charles's data is serialized and written. 
Thread 2: Charles's data is serialized and written.
```

Because Thread 2 was loaded before Thread 1 serialized Charles's favorite food and written afterwards, the update to `FavoriteFood` is completely lost.

A solution to this could be to move the read/modify/write operation into a property for every field, but this seems incredibly inefficient, especially when considering a hypothetical data type with dozens of properties.

To be clear, the goal here is a thread-safe method for storing data on the disk in a human-accessible manner; this doesn't necessarily mean using JSON or even text files. What's the best solution here?

Comment: You should see about posting this question on [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why not use a DB?

Comment: Reinvention of the wheel seems inefficient - there are embeddable DBs like SQLLite and bigger DBs like SQL server that have solved all of these issues.

Comment: Upvoted you back to 0 as it's a well written and researched question so shouldn't have been down voted, however as the others have said, use a database as that's exactly what you are describing and there are many choices. If someone is poking around your JSON and edits something that won't be parsed back in you are going to run in to issues.

Answer (score 1):

One of the patterns that I think would fit what you are doing well is to use a [Repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx) with a `UnitOfWork`, with this, you could alleviate your problem of synchronous data. Supplementing it with [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) and backing it up with a Database would make for a perfectly scalable solution for your needs, also taking a lot of the `I/O` tasks out of the application itself.